# Relativistic momentum for light

Tags: special-relativity, visible-light, momentum, speed-of-light

In special relativity,momentum $p$ is defined by $\gamma mv$ where $\gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$. Again,we are aware of the relation $E^2=(mc^2)^2+(pc)^2$. Now,the momentum of light is deduced by setting $m=0$ in the second equation,from where we get $p=\frac{E}{c}$. But the if we proceed using the relativistic definition of momentum,in that case,the momentum of light would be $\gamma mc$ but since $m=0$ and $v=c$,the momentum $p$ turns out to be undefined in this case. How is this possible when the relativistic definition of momentum is used to prove $E^2=(mc^2)^2+(pc)^2$? Insights on this topic will be greatly helpful?

Comment: Why not just take the equations that are well-behaved and well-defined to be the originally true things, and derive the non-well-defined stuff as a convenient shorthand? That is, take $E=+\sqrt{(mc^2)^2+(pc)^2}$ as the truth for any fixed $m$ and any $\vec p$ and derive that $\vec p=\gamma m\vec v$ as a convenient shorthand?

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent,even if we did we would get $P=\frac{E}{c}$ from the equation and $p$ undefined from the shorthand,what difference does it make?Could you kindly elaborate?It still seems as a contradiction to me.

Comment: No, the fact of the matter is that it is much more natural for us to take momentum as the pre-determined and free variable, and for the shorthand to just not be usable in the massless limit.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent,thank you for commenting. If we are assuming the equation to be derived without defining $p=\gamma mv$,how else can we derive the equation? I am sorry if I am being foolish but almost everywhere I saw the derivation being done by taking $p=\gamma mv$.

Comment: @madness the modern approach is typically to take $(mc^2)^2=(pc)^2-E^2$ as the *definition* of mass in terms of $E$ and $p$, which are independently defined as the conserved quantities associated with time- and space-translation symmetry, respectively. Their particular forms will depend on the model of your physical system. E.g. the expression $p=\gamma mv$ is determined from the Lagrangian of a massive relativistic particle, so it doesn't make sense to apply it to massless particles.

Comment: @KrisWalker since $E\geqslant|p|$ it has to be $mc^2=+\sqrt{E^2-(pc)^2}$ but yes, we take this as the definition of invariant rest mass.

Comment: Thanks @naturallyInconsistent. Not sure how that happened, I must have written that thing a million times!

Answer (score 3):

It goes the other way around. In special relativity, there is an energy-momentum four- vector, whose 'length' is given by the invariant, $m^2c^4=E^2-p^2c^2$.  If $m=0$, the momentum is related to the energy by  $p=E/c$. If m does not equal zero, and the velocity as given by $v=p/E$, the formula $E=mc^2\gamma$ can be derived.

Comment: You could say that the velocity is always given by $pc^2/E$ without needing to say that $m\neq0$